# What is the default password of argocd?

Tags: argocd

I have installed argocd on aks using below command:

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/master/manifests/install.yaml
```

Then I change it to load balancer service.

```
kubectl edit svc argocd-server -n argocd
```

Now, when I connect to argocd web ui, I wasm't able to connect with below credentials.

> user: admin password: argocd-server-9b77b6575-ts54n

Password got from below command as mentioned in docs.

```
kubectl get po -n argocd
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
argocd-application-controller-0      1/1     Running   0          21m
argocd-dex-server-5559bc9679-5mj4v   1/1     Running   1          21m
argocd-redis-74d8c6db65-sxbnt        1/1     Running   0          21m
argocd-repo-server-6866f58df-m59sr   1/1     Running   0          21m
argocd-server-9b77b6575-ts54n        1/1     Running   0          21m
```

Please suggest me how to login, what is the default credentials.

Even I tried resetting it using this command.

```
kubectl -n argocd patch secret argocd-secret -p '{"stringData": {
    "admin.password": "$2a$10$Ix3Pd7mywOwVWOK8eSSY0uo60V6Vf6DtZljGuLwGRHQNnWNBbOLhW",
    "admin.passwordMtime": "'$(date +%FT%T%Z)'"
  }}'
```

But getting this error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 's' looking for beginning of object key string
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "2021-07-08T12:59:15IST" not found
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "\n  }}" not found
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You get the password by typing

```
kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d
```

With `kubectl get pods` you get the pod name, not the password.
It is common that applications save the password into a Kubernetes Secret. The secret values are base64 encoded, so to update the secret it has to be valid base64
`echo newpassword | base64`. Allthough keep in mind updating the secret does not change the application password.

Answer (score 23):

user: `admin`

To get the password, type the command below:

```
kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 5):

Visit https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/faq.md

```
#bcrypt(password)=$2a$10$rRyBsGSHK6.uc8fntPwVIuLVHgsAhAX7TcdrqW/RADU0uh7CaChLa
kubectl -n argocd patch secret argocd-secret \
  -p '{"stringData": {
    "admin.password": "$2a$10$rRyBsGSHK6.uc8fntPwVIuLVHgsAhAX7TcdrqW/RADU0uh7CaChLa",
    "admin.passwordMtime": "'$(date +%FT%T%Z)'"
  }}'
```

your new password is "password"

Comment: missing `'` at the end

Answer (score 5):

Using tools like Rancher or Lens (or OpenLens), you can see the secrets.

You may find the Argocd admin password is in a `argocd-initial-admin-secret` secret (at least for Argocd v2.3.3) :

OpenLens :
[image: Find Argocd admin password using OpenLens]

Rancher :
[image: Find Argocd admin password using Rancher]

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this (Local ArgoCD setup)

1. Patch secret to update password.

```
kubectl -n argocd patch secret argocd-secret  -p '{"data": {"admin.password": null, "admin.passwordMtime": null}}'
```

That will reset the password to the pod name.

2. Restart the api-server pod. Do this by scaling the pod replica to zero and then back to one.

```
kubectl -n argocd scale deployment argocd-server --replicas=0

once scaled-down, make sure to scale back up and wait a few minutes before

kubectl -n argocd scale deployment argocd-server --replicas=1
```

3. New password of the ArgoCD will be your api-server pod name with the numbers at the end name (kubectl -n argocd get po >> to find pod name)

i.e login:

- user: admin
- pass: argocd-server-6cdb9b4b84-jvl58

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

Initial password could also be retrieved using the `argocd` CLI. [Related documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/#4-login-using-the-cli)

- Install the CLI (in Mac using `homebrew`):

```bash
brew install argocd
```

> Installation instructions for other platforms are [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli_installation/)

- Get the initial password

```bash
argocd admin initial-password -n argocd
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer right now

Answer (score 1):

You can get the password by using following command

```bash
kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d
```

To reset password you might remove `admin.password` and `admin.passwordMtime` keys from argocd-secret and restart api server pod. Password will be reset to pod name.

```bash
kubectl patch secret argocd-secret  -p '{"data": {"admin.password": null, "admin.passwordMtime": null}}' -n argocd
```

alternatively once you login you can change the password by using below command from the argocd cli

```bash
argocd account update-password
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the password, edit the argocd-secret secret and update the admin.password field with a new bcrypt hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running ArgoCD > 1.9 then you can reset your admin password by patching `argocd-secret`

```
kubectl -n argocd patch secret argocd-secret \
-p '{"stringData": {"admin.password": "'$(htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" <adminpwd> | tr -d ':\n' | sed 's/$2y/$2a/')'", "admin.passwordMtime": "'$(date +%FT%T%Z)'"}}'
```

replace `<adminpwd>` with your admin password.

It requires you to have [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

Answer (score 0):

A Step-by-Step Guide to Resetting Admin Passwords:

Step 1: Invalidating Admin Credentials

To initiate the password reset, we start by invalidating the current admin credentials. Run the following `kubectl` command to patch the ArgoCD secret:

```
kubectl patch secret argocd-secret -n argocd -p '{"data": {"admin.password": null, "admin.passwordMtime": null}}'
```

This step renders the existing admin password useless, ensuring a clean slate for the upcoming password reset.

— -

Step 2: Restarting ArgoCD Server Pods

Next, to apply the changes made in Step 1, we need to restart the ArgoCD server pods. Execute the following command to gracefully restart the pods:

```
kubectl delete pods -n argocd -l app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server
```

This ensures that the changes take effect and the ArgoCD server picks up the updated secret.

— -

Step 3: Decrypting the New Password

Now that the admin credentials are reset, let’s generate a new password and decrypt it for secure access.

Run the following command to retrieve and decrypt the new password from the `argocd-initial-admin-secret`:

```
kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d
```

This command fetches the base64-encoded password, decodes it, and displays the new admin password.

— -

My Medium article:
[securing-argocd-a-step-by-step-guide-to-resetting-admin-passwords](https://medium.com/@dulanjanalakmal/securing-argocd-a-step-by-step-guide-to-resetting-admin-passwords-bb5236208a64)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and during my troubleshooting process, I discovered that despite all my ArgCD pods being functional, the node group was facing health issues due to insufficient permissions on AWS.

Here's a step-by-step solution:

The admin is generated automatically post-deployment. However, if the node group's health is compromised, the deployment of the argocd-initial-admin-secret pod might be hindered.

Verify the health of the node group and ensure it is in a healthy state.

Ensure that both the Kubernetes cluster and the node group have the necessary permissions.

Refer to the image below for further clarification:

[Node group permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTTcZ.png)